# std::unique_ptr custom deleter moving to another object

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, move, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use custom deleter with `std::unique_ptr` and then I return `std::unique_ptr` to class object through `std::move`. This object will be deleted in the end of program.

This is my definition of custom deleter and function, where it is used:

```
using deleter_wrap_t = std::unique_ptr<Structure1, std::function<void(Structure1*)>>;

static  deleter_wrap_t create_buffer(int32_t size)
{
    printf("Launch>> deleter_wrap_t\n");
    auto buf = deleter_wrap_t(new Structure1(), &CustDeleteFunc);
    if (!buf)
        return nullptr;

    buf->Data = new int32_t[size];
    if (!buf->Data)
        return nullptr;

    buf->dataSize = size;
    return std::move(buf);
}
```

And this is custom deleter function:

```
void CustDeleteFunc(Structure1* pbs)
{
    printf("Launch>> CustDeleteFunc\n");
    if(pbs)
    {
        delete [] pbs->Data;
        pbs->dataSize = 0;
    }
}
```

And after I start the program in output I have:

```
Launch>> deleter_wrap_t
```

And no traces of launching `CustDeleteFunc`

Does anybody know, why `CustDeleteFunc` doesn`t launch and how to make it work?

---

**UPD:**

This is a minimal reproducible example and it works perfect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char* Data;
    int32_t dataSize;
} Structure1;

using deleter_wrap_t = std::unique_ptr<Structure1, std::function<void(Structure1*)>>;

void CustDeleteFunc(Structure1* pbs)
{
    printf("Launch>> CustDeleteFunc\n");
    if (pbs)
    {
        delete[] pbs->Data;
        pbs->dataSize = 0;
    }
}

static  deleter_wrap_t create_buffer(int32_t size)
{
    printf("Launch>> deleter_wrap_t\n");
    auto buf = deleter_wrap_t(new Structure1(), &CustDeleteFunc);
    if (!buf)
        return nullptr;

    buf->Data = new unsigned char[size];
    if (!buf->Data)
        return nullptr;

    buf->dataSize = size;
    return std::move(buf);
}


class myClass{
public:
    myClass(){
        printf("constructor\n");
    };
    void init(){
        m_dst = create_buffer(3);
        auto tmp = m_dst.get();
        tmp->dataSize = 0;
    };

    virtual ~myClass() noexcept
    {
        close();
    };

protected:
    deleter_wrap_t m_dst;
    void close() noexcept{
        //m_dst.reset(); //commented or not - it works clear
    }
};


int main() {
    myClass m;
    m.init();
    return 0;
}
```

So now, I'm in dismay, because min example works well, and in my large project it doesn`t work, so I get memory leak.

In project m_ww can be pointed by some other objects (as `tmp` in exaple above), but these `tmp`s doesn`t affect on deleter.

**So have you got any answers/assumptions what can cause this behavior, that `CustDeleteFunc` doesn`t call?**

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. We can't tell you why something happens if you don't show the code.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to use `std::function` here?

Comment: `Data = new int32_t[size];` should be handled in `Structure1`'s constructor, and `delete [] Data;` should be handled in `Structure1`'s destructor, not in a custom deleter of `std::unique_ptr`. This code shouldn't be using a custom deleter at all. Get rid of that, and then you can use `std::unique_ptr<Structure1>` with its standard default deleter.  But either way, `return std::move(buf);` should just be `return buf;`

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/erjZvp You are forgetting to `delete pbs;` in your custom deleter though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau @NikosC. I 've tryed to do it only through ```std::unique_ptr<Structure1>``` with default deleter and it works good, but I want to sort out why it doesn`t work with custom deleter

@super I've updated the post with min reproduciable example

Comment: @KirillSuverov [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/xbAD6o) the problem using the [mcve] you provided.  The custom deleter is called, as expected. Please provide a [mcve] that DOESN'T call the custom deleter.